# Adding line break after every 6th comma

Tags: php

I have string like **21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38** how can I add a line break after every 6th comma?

```
    21,22,23,24,25,26,
    27,28,31,32,33,34,
    35,36,37,38
```

Comment: Homework? If you plan to learn then you should also provide what you have tried an where you got stuck.

Comment: your output differs from the input string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `array_chunk`, `array_map`, `explode` and `implode` functions:

```
$s = "21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38";
$chunks = array_chunk(explode(",", $s), 6);

$result = rtrim(implode(PHP_EOL, array_map(function($v) { 
    return implode(',', $v) . ','; 
}, $chunks)), ',');

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
21,22,23,24,25,26,
27,28,31,32,33,34,
35,36,37,38
```

Comment: Your approach puts comma after 38 as well, your output is wrong. @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @tufanayd, check again, now it's fine

Answer (score 5):

one approach could be to split the input strings, group individual parts into chunks of fixed size and then join these chunks back:

```
$s="21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38";

$arr = explode(",", $s);
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 6);

$L = array();
foreach($chunks as $chunk){
    $L[] = implode(",", $chunk);
}
$ret = implode(",\n", $L);
var_dump($ret);
```

this produces

```
string(49) "21,22,23,24,25,26,
27,28,31,32,33,34,
35,36,37,38"
```

The code above can be further shortened as:

```
$arr = explode(",", $s);
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 6);
$ret = implode(",\n", array_map(function($x){ return implode(",", $x);}, $chunks));
```

Comment: Your approach seems okay, however after 6th comma, it replaces the comma with the line break. I need to show the comma and add the line break. @ewcz

Answer (score 0):

this is the logic that i can think about it,
ignore it if its gonna affect performace,

```
$s = "21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38";
    $loop = explode(",",$s);
    $new_val = '';
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($loop as $key=>$val)
    {
        $new_val .= $val.',';
        if($counter % 6 ==0)
        {
            $new_val .= '\n';
        }
        $counter++;
    }
    echo $new_val;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it with this function,

```
function insertNewline($str, $delim, $pos){
    return preg_replace('/((.*?'.$delim.'){'.$pos.'})/',"$1" . PHP_EOL,$str);
}

$x = "21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38";
echo insertNewline($x, ',', 6);
```